Why am I getting the warning "No utility classes were detected in your source files" while configuring my local Tailwind CSS, & how can I resolve it?
I am a beginner coder, and started coding a while ago. After going with vanilla CSS for sometime, i tries to learn a CSS framework, and i selected tailwind.css as a framework of my choice after some searching and some homework. But since, day one, i am facing different issues with it.

I am using visual studio code as my IDE, and I'm trying to run my real time tailwind.css generator with the code npx tailwindcss -i "D:/Practice/Web/Contact List/src/input.css" -o "D:/Practice/Web/Contact List/style.css" --watch.
Please note that my project is in the folder "Contact List", and the "input.css" file is in the folder "src", which is inside the "Contact List" folder. While the files "package-lock.json", "package.json" and "tailwind.config.js" is in the same directory where the "Contact List" folder is located, these all are in the folder "Web". The "node modules" folder is also there.

The problem is that whenever, i ran the command npx tailwindcss -i "D:/Practice/Web/Contact List/src/input.css" -o "D:/Practice/Web/Contact List/style.css" --watch, it create the file "style.css", and i checked it and there are also some styles, but my html file is not getting any style. And it also bring 2 errors with itself, which are
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

.
Just for reference, The content of the "tailwind.config.js" file are...
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    'D:/Practice/Web/Contact List/**/*.html',
    'D:/Practice/Web/Contact List/**/*.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      
    },
  },
  plugins: [
     
  ],
}



, and the content of the "input.css" file are...
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.
Plus, i also want you tell suggest me, how can i easily use it in my laptop in offline mode? As it is quite troublesome, every time whenever i close the terminal, it gets stopped and then i do repeat all the process.
Thank You Guyz

I tried, deleting the "style.css" file, and creating again with the command, but it ain't worked for me.
I checked the file "input.css", and it contains

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

which is alright, i think.

I checked the file "tailwind.config.js", and it contains

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    'D:/Practice/Web/Contact List/**/*.html',
    'D:/Practice/Web/Contact List/**/*.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      
    },
  },
  plugins: [
     
  ],
}


which is also okay, i think.

All tailwind utilities are stroe in index.css file. and run I think everything is alright.

Yes all tailwind utilities are there, but still it is not working... I don't know why?

you can check another project.
